# LibGDX: How to detect remote button press for Android TV?

Tags: android, libgdx, keyboard

On Android TV, I need to be able to detect the remote control centre button to start the game.

I tried:

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched() || Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE) || Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.DPAD_CENTER) ||
                Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.ENTER) ||
                Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.BUTTON_SELECT) ||
                Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.BUTTON_START))  {
...}
```

All does not work. The only one that works is isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DPAD_CENTER), but that will return more than one key pressed.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty late but try 
`Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.CENTER)`. 
That works for my Nvidia Shield remote. Also as a side not this is also the A button on the Nvidia Shield controller.